# How can I styling this design only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

I want to design the above image using pure CSS.

Following is the HTML and CSS I have come up with so far:

```
    <div>
      <input
        className="my_file"
        type="file"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setImageSelected(event.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />
        <svg
          width="20"
          height="18"
          viewBox="0 0 20 18"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          className="upload_image_icon"
        >
          <path
            d="M7 0L5.17 2H2C0.9 2 0 2.9 0 4V16C0 17.1 0.9 18 2 18H18C19.1 18 20 17.1 20 16V4C20 2.9 19.1 2 18 2H14.83L13 0H7ZM10 15C7.24 15 5 12.76 5 10C5 7.24 7.24 5 10 5C12.76 5 15 7.24 15 10C15 12.76 12.76 15 10 15Z"
            fill="white"
          
          />
        </svg>
        <Avatar
          src={picture}
          alt="Avatar"
          id="hello"
          className="avatar--profile_image"
        />
    </div>
```

and here is my scss:

```
.profile--card_container {
  width: 348px;
  height: 448px;
  // border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  // border-radius: 5px;



  .avatar--profile_image {
    justify-content: center !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 6.50rem;

    height: 100px !important;
    width: 100px !important;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01) 0px 5px 16px 0px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);

    &:after {
      content:'\A';
      position:absolute;
      width:100%; height:100%;
      top:0; left:0;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      opacity:0;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    &:hover:after {
      opacity:1;
    }
  }

  input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
    
  .my_file {
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s; 
    margin: 45px 0 0 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .upload_image_icon {
    margin: 44px 0 0 144px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

here is how my result look like for now:

[image]

I am trying to achieve like when I hover profile picture the image will overlay black color and appear camera icon. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image within a div. and then use a pesudo-element with a z-index that onyl dispalys when you hover that div like in the snippet below:

```css
.avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

.avatar:hover > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.jpg">
  <div>Icon</div>
</div>
```